# Fatal Signal 11 while locking Android phone

Tags: android, crash, cocos2d-x

I have an android app which is crashing when I press the lock button of my phone. The app works perfectly when I press the home button and resumes it from the task bar. But when I lock the screen it shows the following log and crashes. So when I resume the the app from the task bar it restarts the app.

```
02-07 12:42:09.247: W/Settings(23540): Setting android_id has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
02-07 12:42:09.257: A/libc(23540): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 23554 (Thread-1101)
```

Can somebody help me on this as I am pretty new to Android development. I am using cocos2d-x to develop my app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Place the tag `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` for the `activity` tag in `Manifest` file where you got crash.

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to do this "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 
 'android'"